# Can you move content to a new URL when Google is using it in instant answer box?

Tags: seo, knowledge-graph

If you move content that currently appears in the instant answer box in SERPs to a different URL on the same domain, do you risk losing that position?

Not sure how big a role page authority may play in P0 ranking.

Comment: Why would you want to move a page that Google clearly likes?

Comment: I'm not sure that really helps to answer the question.

Comment: Page Rank is not publicly available any more. Any page past a certain date is always PR 0. PR has been gone for about 4 years now. Be careful. Many so-called SEO ranking sites are garbage and presenting PR is one indication. Be that as it may, moving the page is a risk. My question asks why you want to move the page in the first place when you have reached every webmaster dream?

Comment: It's not the page that would be moving to a different URL, a bit of content on that page that would be moving to a different page/URL. It's one question / answer, not the entirety of the contents of the page, and it would be better placed on a different page.

Comment: *...and it would be better placed on a different page...* Well, if that is the case, then move it. Always do what is best for the user. ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: 301 redirect entered the chat

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you are completely removing the content on the page that Google is surfacing in an instant answer box it is a risk. There is a chance that Google would crawl the page you are placing the content on and choose to use it in an answer box; however, that is not guaranteed.

If you really want to move the content to the other page another creative option would be to summarize the answer on the original page and then internally link to the new page's content with a more robust answer.

This way Google can easily navigate to where the new answer is and hopefully just refresh the URL in search results.

Nevertheless, it is still a risk.